# In javascript how to make multiplication table to be generated by default of 5 or any other number, if the user enters no input number?

Tags: javascript, html-table, multiplication

Write a program to take input a number from user &
display it’s multiplication table on your browser. If user
does not enter a new number, multiplication table of 5
should be displayed by default.

And this is how I want it to be generated with by default table of 5 encoded,

```js
var num = prompt("Enter Number", "0") //prompt user to enter the number
var num = parseInt(num); //parse the num to number
var i = 0;
document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="0">');
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  document.write("<tr><td>" + num + " x " + i + " = " + num * i + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Comment: Maybe simply `prompt("Enter Number", "5")`?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you with your problem. It works like this. if `parseInt(num)` is a truthy(not 0) it'll use `parseInt(num)` else if it is falsy(0) then it'll use 5

```
var num = prompt("Enter Number", "0") //prompt user to enter the number
var num = parseInt(num) || 5;
```